# Excluding target folder from intellij search

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have been trying to exclude maven projects target folders from intellij search.

Even though all target folders of all maven projects are excluded (***File->Project structure->Modules->Excluded folders***), the files in the the target still appear when searching for a filename.

[image]

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean Find in Path or Find Usages? What Scope do you use?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Finding file name

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-165830 may be the case if you are referencing files from the target in the project.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I checked but I didn't find any referencing from the target.

Comment: See if you can reproduce it in some other Maven project.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the folder you want to exclude, you will find the option there.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Saurabh's Answer

- Find the folder you want to exclude in the project tree
- Right click -> "Mark Directory as" -> "Excluded"

[image: mark folder as excluded screenshot]

This will hide files inside the folder from the find filename Dialog (ctrl+shift+N).